# MySQL starting error

Tags: mysql

I installed LAMP not so long ago and it worked fine but ever time I try start MYSQL server I see this thing:

```
$ /etc/init.d/mysql start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.20" (uid=1000 pid=3137 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just take some time to actually read the message since it is not an error. 
Try this instead:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Any change in output?

The reason for this is that **the traditional sysvinit** have been replaced by **Upstart / Services** as of Ubuntu 6.10. However, a great load of packages still use the old sysvinit way, which have been left in place for backwards compability. The biggest difference, apart from having to use another command, is that upstart is event driven, on the contrary of sysvinit which is a sequencial service manager.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to fix. That is not an error. Ubuntu has converted your init.d script to an upstart job so that you use service util to start/stop a service which is much shorter to type than doing /etc/init.d/script

So now, instead of typing `/etc/init.d/mysql start/stop/status` you can just type `service mysql start/stop/status` or `start/stop/status mysql`